# Remove tuples with same elements in two lists

Tags: python

```
a=['-a', ('-c', 'd'), ('-d', 'c')]
b=['-b', ('c', '-d'), ('d', '-c')]
```

Basicly, for each list, if there is some tuple in another list that has the same elements with it, then remove all of those tuples have this elements from both lists.

(I was using sets instead of tuples, but  somewhere in my code got an error
says: unhashable type: 'set', so I changed it to tuples...)

```
res=[]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if type(i) == tuple and type(j) == tuple:
            if i[0] in j and i[1] in j:
                res.append(i)
                res.append(j)
a,b=list(set(a)-set(res)),list(set(b)-set(res))
print(a,b)
```

This gives `a=['a'],b=['-b']`, is there better methods (maybe some simple build in function) to do the same thing ?

---

More examples

```
>>>a=['-a', ('-c', 'd'), ('-d', 'c'), ('-d', 'c')]
>>>b=['-b', ('c', '-d'), ('d', '-c'), ('-d', 'c')]

>a=['a'],b=['-b']

>>>a=['-a', ('a', 'b'),('-c', 'd'), ('-d', 'c'), ('-d', 'c')]
>>>b=['-b', ('c', '-d'), ('d', '-c'), ('-d', 'c')]

>a=['a',('a', 'b')],b=['-b']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `frozenset` On the sub items and you will be able to use `set.difference`:

```
a = ['-a', ('a', 'b'),('-c', 'd'), ('-d', 'c'), ('-d', 'c')]
b = ['-b', ('c', '-d'), ('d', '-c'), ('-d', 'c')]

seta = {frozenset(i) if isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in a}
setb = {frozenset(i) if isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in b}
print(seta - setb, setb - seta)
```

Prints:

```
{'-a', frozenset({'a', 'b'})} {'-b'}
```

I only say this because you said you were using sets before but had issues. You can always turn the frozen sets back to tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following answer. Basically, you just need to find out duplicates first.

```
a = ['-a', ('-c', 'd'), ('-d', 'c')]
b = ['-b', ('-c', 'd'), ('d', '-c')]

to_remove = set(a).intersection(set(b))
a = [i for i in a if i not in to_remove or type(i) != tuple]
b = [j for j in b if j not in to_remove or type(j) != tuple]

print a, b
```

Comment: when a = ['-a', ('a', 'b'),('-c', 'd'), ('-d', 'c'), ('-d', 'c')]
b = ['-b', ('c', '-d'), ('d', '-c'), ('-d', 'c')] it gives ['-a', ('a', 'b'), ('-c', 'd')] ['-b', ('c', '-d'), ('d', '-c')]

Comment: Yes. It's expected to give this. Right? I thought you want to remove all common tuples in both input lists? Isn't it?